# F#: SqlProvider Issue with latest npgsql

Tags: f#, nuget, type-providers

I am trying to use the SQLProvider together with the latest npgsql driver (postgresql)  in a classical dotnet framework solution.
I get the error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   FS3033  The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>   Details: 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.   SqlProviderDotnetFramework

Unfortunately System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0 is not available on nuget anymore. Do you have any suggestion for me?
I have already set

> loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>

, but this do not help.

Comment: Have you tried a binding redirect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#redirecting-assembly-versions-at-the-app-level

Comment: Not sure how I do a binding redirect for the type provider during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to install npgsql into the GAC via the provided MSI file.